# How can I show done button on the decimal pad keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm trying to learn Swift and I've done on the view screens. But as you can understand more easily by checking the screenshot, when I enter a value into a text field, there isn't any done button showing up so I can not hide the keyboard from the screen. And that makes it impossible to press the submit button which is located bottom of the screen view.

[image: screenshoot while the keyboard is being shown]

[image: screenshoot while the keyboard is closed]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, create a new `Swift File`. Add this to the file :

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIViewController{
    func toolBar() -> UIToolbar{
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.barStyle = .default
        toolBar.isTranslucent = true
        toolBar.barTintColor = UIColor.init(red: 0/255, green: 25/255, blue: 61/255, alpha: 1) //Write what you want for color
        let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        var buttonTitle = "Done" //Or "Tamam"
        var cancelButtonTitle = "Cancel" //Or "İptal" for Turkish
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: buttonTitle, style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(onClickDoneButton))
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: cancelButtonTitle, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(onClickCancelButton))
        doneButton.tintColor = .white
        cancelButton.tintColor = .white
        toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, space, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        toolBar.sizeToFit()
        return toolBar
    }

    @objc func onClickDoneButton(){
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

    @objc func onClickCancelButton(){
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

And add this `toolbar` to your `textfield` :

```
yourTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar()
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Also you can use this toolbar wherever you need. Just add "inputAccessoryView" to your textField.

Comment: I appreciate! You've saved my day.

Comment: Happy coding :)

Answer (score 3):

You can add a toolbar as an input accessory :

```
     let toolBar = UIToolbar()
     toolBar.sizeToFit()
     let button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, 
                                      action: #selector(dismiss))
     toolBar.setItems([button], animated: true)
     toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
     textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```

Also you need to add dismiss method:

```
@objc func dismiss() {
   view.endEditing(true)
 }
```

Comment: It returns Ambiguous use of 'dismiss' on the line where the button is defined

Comment: You need to write first code in viewDidload or where you are configuring your view. And second one in the swift file.

Comment: This does not work without subclassing the referenced textField because inputAccessoryView's setter is not accessible. Or am I getting something wrong here?

Comment: This should be accessible. Can you share the code so that i can be help

Answer (score -2):

Without switching back to UIKit Used the following library

Link: https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect

```
import SwiftUI
import Introspect

struct ContentView : View {
@State var text = ""

var body: some View {
    TextField("placeHolder", text: $text)
       .keyboardType(.default)
       .introspectTextField { (textField) in
           let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: textField.frame.size.width, height: 44))
           let flexButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
           let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(textField.doneButtonTapped(button:)))
           doneButton.tintColor = .systemPink
           toolBar.items = [flexButton, doneButton]
           toolBar.setItems([flexButton, doneButton], animated: true)
           textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        }
}

extension  UITextField {
   @objc func doneButtonTapped(button:UIBarButtonItem) -> Void {
      self.resignFirstResponder()
   }
}
```