# dismiss keyboard after input

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to build my first iOS app with swift 5.
I have a textfield where the user should type a value like 15,00

this is my result at the moment:

[image]

I searched for a solution to dismiss the keyboard.

Option 1: dismiss keyboard after user type a format like xx,xx
Option 2: a "Done" button im keyboard with decimal pad style

But I don't know, how I can realize any of this option.
Need help ! :)

Comment: There's already an answer for the `Done` button option and IMO it's better in terms of UX: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61332009/how-can-i-show-done-button-on-the-decimal-pad-keyboard. Also consider dismissing the keyboard on background tap.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code to your didLoad

```
 var toolbar = UIToolbar()
 toolbar.sizeToFit()
 var flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
 var doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.done, target: self, action: #selector(yourFunc))
 toolbar.setItems([flexibleSpace, doneButton], animated: true)
 yourTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
```

When click done button you can do whatever you want but we want to do dismiss keyboard

```
@objc func doneClicked(){
    searchBar.endEditing(true)
}
```